# EF Code First - Two Tables, Two relationships

Tags: entity-framework-4.1, code-first

i'm with a trouble;

For initial imagine that we have an entity Member, and Member has Projects..

If you ask: Do projects have members? Yes they have...

Members (N*) <-> Project (N*) - so is a n-n-relationship.

But in my domain application i wanna say too that one Member is responsible for N projects, and one Project has one Member..

```
 public class Member : User
{
    public virtual ICollection<Project> ProjectsResponsable { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Project> ProjectsWorker { get; set; }
}
public class Project
{
    public virtual int ProjectID { get; set; }
    public virtual String Name { get; set; }
    public virtual bool Enabled { get; set; }
    public virtual DateTime CreatedDate { get; set; }
    public virtual String Description { get; set; }

    public virtual Member Responsable { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Member> Workers { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Issue> Issues { get; set; }
}
```

For ProjectsWorker property in Worker will be a N-N relationship between Member and Project, but with this (the EF framework only creates for me the 1-way relashionship)

My question is... who can i a map these two relationships with code-first.
I was using DatabaseFirst, and now with code-first it appears to be very powerful but restrict me a little now.

Comment: What is your question?  Are you looking to have only one member per project, but let members have n-number of projects?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must tell EF which relationships belong together. You can do this either with data annotations ...

```
public class Member : User
{
    [InverseProperty("Responsable")]
    public virtual ICollection<Project> ProjectsResponsable { get; set; }
    [InverseProperty("Workers")]
    public virtual ICollection<Project> ProjectsWorker { get; set; }
}

public class Project
{
    public virtual int ProjectID { get; set; }
    // ...
    [InverseProperty("ProjectsResponsable")]
    public virtual Member Responsable { get; set; }
    [InverseProperty("ProjectsWorker")]
    public virtual ICollection<Member> Workers { get; set; }
    // ...
}
```

(I believe the `InverseProperty` attribute is only necessary on one side of the relationship, but I am not sure.)

... or in Fluent API:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    modelBuilder.Entity<Member>()
        .HasMany(m => m.ProjectsResponsable)
        .WithOptional(p => p.Responsable)  // or WithRequired(...)
        .WillCascadeOnDelete(false);

    modelBuilder.Entity<Member>()
        .HasMany(m => m.ProjectsWorker)
        .WithMany(p => p.Workers)
        .Map(a => {
            a.ToTable("MemberProjects");
            a.MapLeftKey("MemberID");
            a.MapRightKey("ProjectID");
        });
}
```

Comment: Thanks Slauma is really that what i need, thanks for your time :)

Comment: @Slauma i think you are the right person to help me with the follow: As you can see, member extends from User... and i got one more Entity: Client that extends too, so my schema will have 3 tables, User, Member and Client. I Need to have one more relashionship between Project and Client, that is.. Project haves one client and one client haves N projects.. Look the next message to view what i am definind in the FluentAPI

Comment: modelBuilder.Entity<Client>()
                        .HasMany(c => c.Projects)
                        .WithRequired(p => p.Client)
                        .WillCascadeOnDelete(false);

Comment: Now i see two problems, the primary key in Client must be the base classe (USERID) plus the id of the project... and more when i see the schema EF dont generate for me the projectID in the Client table... Here is the error: Entities in 'VirtualNoteDb.Projects' participate in the 'Client_Projects' relationship. 0 related 'Client_Projects_Source' were found. 1 'Client_Projects_Source' is expected.

Comment: @gonçaloR: Why do you expect a `ProjectID` in the `Client` table? If a client has *many* projects (as your mapping says) then there must be a `ClientID` in the `Project` table. That's the way how a one-to-many relationship is modeled in a relational database. The foreign key is on the *many* side of the relationship - and this is the `Project` table in your case. EF just follows this standard and therefore doesn't create a `ProjectID` in the Client table, but it will have created a `ClientID` in the `Project` table.

Comment: @Slauma: Oh man i made confusion.... you will ask how? .. Navigation Properties.. As i added an ICollection<Project> in Client i thought that will create a foreign key in client table.. bah :| You are right.. and now i already understood the problem and i already fixed. Was confusion that i made

Comment: you know if is possible configure on modelBuilder which Entities get related entities instead i use Include method on my LINQ queries?

Comment: gonçaloR: No, it's not possible. You must use either `Include` or lazy loading or explicite loading to get related entities. There is no way to specify this in any configuration.